# using unconditional basis

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, schauder-basis

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
Q1 is how to show that "the unconditionality of $\mathcal{B}$
implies $$\|P_{(B\cup A)^c}(x)\| = \|P_{(B\cup A)^c}(x-y)\|\leq
K_{su} \|x-y\|.$$ Analogously, $$\|P_{A\backslash B}(x)\| =
\|P_{A\backslash B}(x-y)\| \leq K_{su}\|x-y\|.$$"

Comment: First time I see some political terminology comes into the math, democratic? So is there autocratic basis? What book is it, would mind to tell here?

Comment: Topics in Banach space theory 
Fernando Albania and nigel

Comment: @user284331 I rather think Roba means Fernando Albiac and Nigel J. Kalton as the authors of *Topics in Banach Space Theory*

Comment: That said, in the version I have this is theorem 9.6.3 and the notation is slightly different, so perhaps OP could clarify?